# One of my fields is missing in my AJAX form

Tags: php, ajax, forms, variables

For some reason one of the variables on my form just isn't going through to PHP and I have no idea why.

```
<form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>Username: </div>
    <input id="username" type="text" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16">
    <span id="unamestatus"></span>
    <div>Email Address:</div>
    <input id="email" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">
    <div>Create Password:</div>
    <input id="pass1" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Confirm Password:</div>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Unique Company ID:</div>
    <input id="companyID" type="number" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    <div>Company Name:</div>
    <input id="compname" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    <div>Country:</div>
```

This calls to ajax where the vars are set and sent using send. as follows

```
function signup(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var cid = _("companyID").value;
    var cn = _("compname").value;
    var status = _("status");
```

Variables are set and put into the send code:

```
ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&cid="+cid+"&cn"+cn);
```

Which then leads up to the PHP where they are set as variables in PHP:

```
// GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
$u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
$p = $_POST['p'];
$cid = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['cid']);
$cn = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9.\- ]#', '', $_POST['cn']);
```

but a few lines down this if statement keeps firing.

```
else if ($cn == ""){
    echo "There is no variable in company name";
    exit();
```

And when I go to check in my database, I see nothing in the company name field after I comment out this `if` statement, but all the other variables are in there. The only variable that doesn't work with is compname (`$cn`).

I could really use the help here, I'm pulling my hair out trying to thing what's wrong.

Comment: Look at the 'Network' tab of Chrome developer tools to see _exactly_ what the browser is sending to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an equals sign in this line:

```
ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&cid="+cid+"&cn"+cn);
```

becomes

```
ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&cid="+cid+"&cn="+cn);
```